# How to disappear the text view?

Tags: android

I have a problem when I try to disappear the text, I'm making a program with five buttons than change the background color (the buttons are down) but what I want to do is after click on the screen the text should disappear but when I click on the screen my buttons go up and I do know how to solve this problem.

```
 myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

             myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              myText.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
                if(myLayout2.getVisibility()!=View.INVISIBLE)
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                else
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

            }

        });
```

Comment: use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
myText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

```
visible     0    Visible on screen; the default value.
invisible   1    Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
gone        2    Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: @jaimito read  invisible means Not displayed. view is not displayed but space is taken.

Comment: @jaimito use `myText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. Use `View.INVISIBLE` for the view required.

Answer (score 2):

use View.INVISIBLE istead of View.GONE

```
 myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

             myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              myText.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                if(myLayout2.getVisibility()!=View.INVISIBLE )
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE ); 
                else
                    myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `View.INIVISIBLE` otherwise the textView will be gone, and you cannot make it visible again.

Comment: But that is what I want to do... disappear completely the textView after one click

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
myText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

this hides the view from screen and keeps the references(margins) of the screen and also dependencies of other controls on this view.And if you are going to use this:

```
myText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then the view will be vanished from screen and other controls dependancies will be cleared like if you have `android:below` or `android:above` so `View.INVISIBLE` is good practice.